# Replace Widget in Stack with Keys

Tags: flutter, dart

In the Flutter [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) documentation, you can use [Keys](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack/key.html) to replace a Widget in Stack Widget. You can use GlobalKeys in the **key** property. The problem is, I have no idea how to use the keys to replace the Widget in the Stack Widget. I would like to get a full example to replace a Widget in the Stack with they GlobalKey.

Comment: Can you please post the code whatever you tried so far? So that people can help you correcting your code.

Comment: I want to replace a Widget In the Stack Widget

Comment: so rebuild your `Stack` with new children list

Comment: I want to replace the widget with a buttonpress

Answer (score 0):

it's not for widget positions

> Controls how one widget replaces another widget in the tree.

For your situation use positioned widget

> A widget that controls where a child of a Stack is positioned.

if you need position of widget to set another widget position you can use of first one key like below

```dart
  final keyContext = fisrtWidgetKey.currentContext;
  if (keyContext != null) {
    box = keyContext.findRenderObject();
    if (box != null) pos = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
  }
```

pos contain dx and dy of the widget you have passed it's key